# Buscar item en objeto de 'n' niveles de forma recursiva

Tags: javascript, recursión

Estoy trabajando con un objeto que puede contener objetos en su interior y así de manera sucesiva. Lo que necesito es crear una función que pueda encontrar cualquier **elemento** sin importar la profundidad del objeto.

He intentado hacerlo de manera recursiva, pero solo funciona en el primer objeto interno que encuentra.

```
     const destinos = {
      'standar': {
        'continente': {
          'america': 'mexico',
          'asia': 'china'
        }
      },
      'lujoso': {
        'continente': {
          'europa': {
            'este': 'rusia',
            'oeste': 'francia'
          },
          'america': 'canada',
          'asia': 'japon',
        }
      },
    
    }
    
    
    function buscarDestino(data, destino) {
      for (const item in data) {
        if (typeof data[item] === 'string' && data[item] === destino) return true
    
        if (typeof data[item] === 'object') return buscarDestino(data[item], destino)
      }
    
      return false
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola te recomiendo que hagas una prueba de escritorio, te darás cuenta que aunque se cumpla la condición donde encuentras el destino ingresado, sigues dentro del bucle for, ya que al ser una función recursiva, continuas con el flujo del programa.

Te dejo la respuesta, espero te sirva.

Saludos!

```js
const destinos = {
  'standar': {
    'continente': {
      'america': 'mexico',
      'asia': 'china'
    }
  },
  'lujoso': {
    'continente': {
      'europa': {
        'este': 'rusia',
        'oeste': 'francia'
      },
      'america': 'canada',
      'asia': 'japon',
    }
  },

}

let res = false;

function buscarDestino(data, destino) {
  res = false;
  for (const item in data) {
    if (res == true) {
      break;
    }

    if (typeof data[item] === 'object') {
      buscarDestino(data[item], destino);
    } else if (typeof data[item] === 'string' && data[item] === destino) {
      res = true;
      return;
    }
  }
}

 buscarDestino(destinos,'mexico');
 console.log("Destino mexico: "+res);
 buscarDestino(destinos,'brazil');
 console.log("Destino brazil: "+res);
```

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de usar objetos anidados uso arrays anidados, el principio es el mismo

```
const tree = [1,[2,3,[7,8,9]],4,[5,6,[10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,[21,[23,24,25,[31,32,33],26],22],17,18]],19,20];
var found = false;

function search(targetnumber,struct){
    for(let i=0;i<struct.length;i++){
        if(Array.isArray(struct[i])) search(targetnumber,struct[i])
        else if(struct[i]==targetnumber){
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return [found,targetnumber]; 
}

var answer = search(33,tree);

(answer[0]==true) ? console.log(`element ${answer[1]} has been found`)
                  : console.log(`element ${answer[1]} not found`)
```

la funcion recorre el array (que en este caso representa un arbol no binario) en busca del numero y si encuentra otros arrays se ejecuta otra vez sobre estos y asi sucesivamente. Cuando encuentra el numero sale de los bucles generados y devuelve un array con el resultado true/false y el numero que evaluamos. Sirve para arboles de cualquier grado pero si queres algoritmos de busqueda para arboles binarios te recomiendo investigar: [ejemplo](https://hhmosquera.wordpress.com/arbolesbinarios/)